# Setting up postgres database for recipes

Tags: json, postgresql, api

I am new to PostgreSQL and trying to plan a database that will allow me to query recipes based on id, ingredients etc from a provided dataset, example below.

I am getting a bit thrownoff by the nested ingredients and how to lay out my tables.

I was initially thinking two tables one for instructions and image and another for the ingredients.

i was now wondering if i am on the right lines and if so how to loop through the nested ingredients to produce a useful second table

enter code here

```
  [  {
 "id": "recipe-88",
 "imageUrl": "http://www.images.com/12",
 "instructions": "blend with oat milk and ice, sprinkle with 
 salt",
 "ingredients": [
   { "name": "blueberries", "grams": 114 },
   { "name": "coffee", "grams": 20 },
   { "name": "kale", "grams": 48 }
 ]
},
{
 "id": "recipe-74",
 "imageUrl": "http://www.images.com/2",
 "instructions": "crush ingredients with mortar and pestle, mix 
 with whole milk, serve in bowl",
 "ingredients": [
   { "name": "coffee", "grams": 25 },
   { "name": "lime", "grams": 140 },
   { "name": "strawberries", "grams": 3 },
   { "name": "apricots", "grams": 24 },
   { "name": "kale", "grams": 50 }
 ]
},
{
 "id": "recipe-77",
 "imageUrl": "http://www.images.com/25",
 "instructions": "blend with oat milk and ice, sprinkle with 
  salt",
 "ingredients": [
   { "name": "coconut", "grams": 14 },
   { "name": "coconut", "grams": 57 },
   { "name": "lime", "grams": 153 },
   { "name": "oat milk", "grams": 31 }
 ]
},]
```

Comment: sorry not sure how to add the remaining data example

Comment: on first sight, i would go with single table `recipe` where `instructions` column is of type `text` and `ingredients` is of type `json(b)`. Another option is to have `ingredients` table which would contain `recipeId` for reference, so you can use `left or inner join`. One or another might be better fit. You might play and try both.

Comment: In addition to what Stefan said , you can have a sequence generated Primary key Column and make colum "id" unique key. Integer based PK's are small and fast to access and defining and unique key on the  the ID column makes it eligible for foreign key reference. Since ,all attributes are one to one related , it can be in one table.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, I tried to enter the ingredients as json b but got a warning regarding too many expressions than columns inserted so i think i made an eror there , the out put looks like below 

[
    'recipe-87',
    'http://www.images.com/5',
    'serve deconstructed on a wooden board',
    [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  ]

Answer (score 0):

I have parsed the json you provided and loaded it in a table.
Check the [dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b676f06f32a787eebc82658620c0155d).

Here is the parsed content loaded into a table.

```
postgres=# select * from parsedjj;
 id | recipe_id |        imageurl         |                                 instructions                                  |                                                                                ingredients
----+-----------+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | recipe-88 | http//www.images.com/12 | blend with oat milk and ice, sprinkle with salt                               | [{"name": "blueberries", "grams": 114}, {"name": "coffee", "grams": 20}, {"name": "kale", "grams": 48}]
  2 | recipe-74 | http//www.images.com/2  | crush ingredients with mortar and pestle, mix  with whole milk, serve in bowl | [{"name": "coffee", "grams": 25}, {"name": "lime", "grams": 140}, {"name": "strawberries", "grams": 3}, {"name": "apricots", "grams": 24}, {"name": "kale", "grams": 50}]
  3 | recipe-77 | http//www.images.com/25 | blend with oat milk and ice, sprinkle with   salt                             | [{"name": "coconut", "grams": 14}, {"name": "coconut", "grams": 57}, {"name": "lime", "grams": 153}, {"name": "oat milk", "grams": 31}]
(3 rows)
```

**Note**: I had changed the  JSON key value from "imageUrl" to "image" because possibly "url" which is a keyword for postgres might have been impeding the parsing.